# method other than Response.Write to display output in content area of aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project related to database. I have designed the home page having various web controls(say buttons). Now, on clicking the button,the function in code behind page gets called. Currently, I am using Response.Write Method in c# code to display the output on Web page because lot of processing from database is required ,but output is getting display above the header which is designed in aspx page. I wish to display the output inside the content area of aspx page.so,is there any method other than Response.Write to display output in content area of aspx page? please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a control and put that control on the page, then write from the control itself, this will write wherever you put the control on the page

Answer (score 0):

Put some asp label in your content area, give some ID to lable like `lblResponse`

On button click you can access that label

```
//button_click code
lblResponse.Text = "<What ever text>";
```

Comment: but specifying number of labels will not help me because contents will get generate dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by `contents will get generate dynamically.` ? If you want you can create Label/any other control from button click code and do your operations